# Stored Procedure no lee if si es NULL en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

tengo un problema con mi codigo y es el siguiente.

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me devuelve valores, como es "Nombre", "Usuario" y "tiempo".

Esto debo de llamarlo a una pagina en PHP, hasta alli todo esta bien, pero el problema es que si aqui no figura nada, ningun valor, se redirija a otra pantalla.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
    <?php
session_start();
include "ms_connection.php"; //Datos de la DB
$name = $_REQUEST['user']; //Usuario
$ssn  = $_REQUEST['pass']; //PASS
$sql = "EXEC [Conductores].[ConductoresSelectAcceso] 'MT4', '" . $name . "' , '" . $ssn . "'"; //PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $procedure_params); 
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {  //VERIFICAMOS SI ALGO ANDA MAL
    echo "Your code is fail!";
    die;
}
if( sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {  //EJECUTAMOS EL SP
    echo 'paso <br />';
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){  //le damos valores
        if ($row != ""){
            echo 'no hay datos'; 
        }else if ($row[1] = "" || $row[1] = NULL ){ //aqui deberia de redirigir a otra pagina si no encuenta ningun valor
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: http://www.ejemplo.es");
            exit;
        }else{
            //ll
        }
    }   
}else{
    print_r( sqlsrv_errors());

}
?>
```

Me podrian indicar si algo anda mal en mi codigo.

Saludos !

Comment: Has intentado con empty() o isset()?

Answer (score 0):

parece que faltan aclarar la declaracion SQL... pregunta que deseas consultar?

en el manual PHP se muestra asi:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Table_1
        SET OrderQty = ?
        WHERE SalesOrderID = ?";

$qty = 0; $id = 0;
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, array( $qty, $id));
if( !$stmt ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

El procedimiento de parametros lo veo declarado pero no seteado, debiese ser un array con los dateos que recibes de $_REQUEST

```
$procedure_params = [$name, $ssn];
```

como idea por un codigo mas seguro podrias usar PDO y al rescatar las variables sanitiza las variables.

```
$datoSinHackers= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dato', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```